# How to automate autocomplete textbox

Tags: java, selenium, autocomplete, ui-automation

I am trying to automate a testcase where textbox provides intelligence to autocomplete the field. 
Please find the link below for autocomplete text box :
http://demoqa.com/autocomplete/

Please find the code written by me

```
  dr.findElement(By.id("tagss")).sendKeys("a");
  Thread.sleep(300);
//  dr.findElement(By.id("ui-id-53")).click();
  Actions act = new Actions(dr);
  act.moveToElement(dr.findElement(By.id("ui-id-53"))).click().build().perform();
```

This code is unable to find and locate options in intelligence provided by browser. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to locate the auto-suggested option element in the DOM because HTML id for those options changes after page reloads.

In this case, you need to use XPath to identify the element. Suppose you want to click on Java auto-suggested option, then your code should be -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDriver\\TestAutomation\\grid\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://demoqa.com/autocomplete/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("tagss")).sendKeys("a");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-1"))));
WebElement javaOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[@class='ui-menu-item' and text()='Java']"));
javaOption.click();
```

Its not good practice to use `Thread.sleep();`

hope this help you.

Comment: I tried but  my reputation is 11 and it says my reputation is not sufficient to do so. Sorry about that amol

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using dynamic id which may change at runtime.
Try this code and let me know for any queries -

```
public class AutoSuggest {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            try {

                  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ranosys\\workspace\\MyTest\\chromedriver.exe");
                  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                  WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,50 );

                  driver.manage().window().maximize();

                  driver.get("http://demoqa.com/autocomplete/");
                  driver.findElement(By.id("tagss")).sendKeys("a");
                  Actions act = new Actions(driver);
                  List<WebElement> lst= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[contains(@id,'ui-id')]"));
                  for(WebElement element:lst){
                      element.click();
                      break;
                  }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its working. I changed the code little bit. ` List<WebElement> option = dr.findElements(By.className("ui-menu-item"));
  
   
   for(WebElement x : option)
   {
    if(x.getText().toLowerCase().equals("java"))
    {
     x.click();
    }
   }`